# scoreboard will not update -- RPS game using javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript and I'm creating a RPS game. For some reason it is only recording points when I play the scissor button. I'm pretty sure I'm using something off that shouldn't be closed, but I can't find where. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's my javascript code:

```
var bot = 0;
var you = 0; 

document.getElementById('rock').onclick = playRock;


function playRock() {
   var humanChoice = 'rock';
   var compChoice = cChoice();
   console.log(compChoice);
   compare(humanChoice, computerChoice);
   };


 function compare(humanChoice2, compChoice2) {
   if (humanChoice2 == compChoice2) {
    console.log("tie")
   } else if (humanChoice2 == "rock"){
    if (compChoice2 == 'scissors') {
        you = you + 1;
        document.getElementById("humanScore").innerHTML = you;
    }
    else {
        bot = bot + 1;
        document.getElementById("computerScore").innerHTML = bot;
    }
}

}

 function cChoice() {
computerChoice = Math.random();
    if (computerChoice <= .33) {
        computerChoice = 'rock';
    } else if (computerChoice <= .66) {
        computerChoice = 'paper';
    } else {
        computerChoice = 'scissors';
    }
    return computerChoice;
}

 document.getElementById('paper').onclick = playPaper;

  function playPaper() {
  var humanChoice = 'paper';
  var compChoice = cChoice();
  console.log(compChoice);
  compare(humanChoice, computerChoice);

};

 function compare(humanChoice2, compChoice2) {
  if (humanChoice2 == compChoice2) {
    console.log("tie")
  } else if (humanChoice2 == "paper"){
    if (compChoice2 == 'rock') {
        you = you + 1;
        document.getElementById("humanScore").innerHTML = you;
    }
    else {
        bot = bot + 1;
        document.getElementById("computerScore").innerHTML = bot;
    }
}

}

 function cChoice() {
computerChoice = Math.random();
    if (computerChoice <= .33) {
        computerChoice = 'rock';
    } else if (computerChoice <= .66) {
        computerChoice = 'paper';
    } else {
        computerChoice = 'scissors';
    }
    return computerChoice;
}

document.getElementById('scissors').onclick = playScissors;

function playScissors() {
var humanChoice = 'scissors';
var compChoice = cChoice();
console.log(compChoice);
compare(humanChoice, computerChoice);

};

function compare(humanChoice2, compChoice2) {
if (humanChoice2 == compChoice2) {
    console.log('tie')
} else if (humanChoice2 == 'scissors'){
    if (compChoice2 == 'paper') {
        you = you + 1;
        document.getElementById('humanScore').innerHTML = you;
    }
    else {
        bot = bot + 1;
        document.getElementById('computerScore').innerHTML = bot;
    }
}
}

function cChoice() {
  computerChoice = Math.random();
    if (computerChoice <= .33) {
        computerChoice = 'rock';
    } else if (computerChoice <= .66) {
        computerChoice = 'paper';
    } else {
        computerChoice = 'scissors';
    }
    return computerChoice;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How can you have three functions with same signature? **compare(humanChoice2, compChoice2)**

Only the last definition is used. Try naming each function differently.

```
function a()
{
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "1";
}

function a()
{
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "2";
}

function a()
{
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "3";
}

a();
```

This will set innerHTML for demo as 3

Comment: Thank you for the comments, but this still doesn't work. I'm trying to figure out why.

Comment: Thank you so much! After re-reading and re-reading what you all were saying, I FINALLY understood! I changed the function name and it works! Merry Christmas!